# Orthophoto Free Download?

Tags: image, orthophoto, data, africa

I'm looking for Image datas for East Africa. Specifically for Rwanda. Does anyone know if such data are available at all free? My target is to digitize roads and buildings with the help of image datas.

I am working with Grass GIS. My job is to find small hydro Power sites. I already did that. For these locations special boundary conditions must be accomplish. E.g. Accessibility of a location (maximum distance to roads about 2000 meter) and a maximum distance to the consumer needs to be defined. Because there are no vector datas of buildings and roads, I need the Image Datas to digitize them.

Comment: You may want to ask a similar question on the opendata.stackexchange.com/  Stack Exchange

Comment: You may want to revise your question and provide some more specific details. Your last sentence is somewhat confusing - orthoimagery is usually fairly high resolution, say 1m. Do you specifically *not* want high resolution, or it doesn't *need* to be? What is your target or acceptable range of resolution? What do you plan to use the imagery for (this can help in suggesting sources).

Comment: Thanks for feedback. It doesn´t need to be high resolution. My target is to digitize buildings and roads with the help of image datas. However, I find generally no image data for Rwanda. I'm sorry I did not know that orthoimagery is a high resolution conditionally.

Comment: I am unclear about what your end goal is. Google maps/earth has digitized roads etc and with Google Earth Pro being free now, can you not find what you are seeking there?

Comment: I am working with Grass GIS. My job is to find small hydro Power sites. I already did that. For these locations special boundary conditions must be accomplish. E.g. 
Accessibility of a location (maximum distance to roads about 2000 meter) and a maximum distance to the consumer needs to be defined.

Comment: For that purpose you *will* want fairly high resolution imagery, say in the 1-5m range. You *might* be able to get away with 15m but that would really be pushing it. Depending on how accurately you plan to digitize anyway. Remember resolution is pixel size, so 30m resolution is one pixel for a 30x30m square on the ground and if your road is only 5m wide... Regarding Google as some have suggested, you might want to take a look at [this blog post](http://geospatial-solutions.com/ortho-imagery-pay-or-play-free/) I found while doing some research on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). You can search many different datasets depending on avaliablity for certian locations.

Comment: I already did. But I only can find something for the USA and some other parts.

Answer (score 2):

you can digitize roads and other objects of your desire from Google earth pro which will be in a kml format that can be converted into shapefiles . you can then use the shape files in gis softwares...